# iOS - Core data - completion handler

Tags: ios, core-data

**Overview**

- I have a iOS project that uses core data
- The core data is used by view controllers as well as for notifications

**Implementation**

- Created a singleton class for database activities called `DatabaseEngine`
- In the appDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, `DatabaseEngine` is instantiated
- `DatabaseEngine` contains properties (delegate) for the view controller and for notifications
- In the `viewDidLoad` of the view controller I am setting the `DatabaseEngine` delegate to the view controller instance
- Once the database is opened, the completion handler (through the delegate properties) calls  the methods to setup the view controller and notifications

**Concern (Timing issue)**

- I am concerned there might be scenario (a timing issue), where the `DatabaseEngine` is created first and at that moment the view controller's `viewDidLoad` would not be executed, and therefore the `DatabaseEngine` delegate would not initialized, therefore the database would execute the completionHandler but since the delegate is nil, no tasks would be done

**What I have done to address the concern**

- Inside the view controller's viewDidLoad, I am checking if the Database is up and if the view controller is not loaded, if yes then i execute the tasks (setting up the views of the view controller) again.

**Note-** I am NOT using threads explicitly but based on my understanding completionHandler is executed asynchronously.

**Question**

1. I have tried it several times, and the view controller data is loaded correctly and there seems to be no timing issue. I even tried looping through a large value(to create a delay) and still there is no timing issue. I wonder why ?
2. Is my implementation a good design or is there a better way to do this ?
3. Is that the correct way to address my concern ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design is a bit convoluted, but seems solid. (I prefer to have core data managed by the app delegate, but your approach is just as fine if you prefer it.)

I would, however, use the usual pattern of lazy initialization of your DatabaseEngine class. In this way, when it is needed and really does not exist, it will create itself and do the necessary initialization routines while the view controller will wait until the call to the engine returns something.

```
// in view controller viewDidLoad, e.g.
self.managedObjectContext = [databaseEngine managedObjectContext];
```

If the context is not initialized, it will happen here.

Comment: thank you so much!! thats a good idea to do lazy instantiation inside the accessor of managedObjectContext!

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach too is to have your app delegate manage the data. Seems like the best approach, and it is what a default CD application template does.

I would look into using MagicalRecord, which is pretty amazing if you ask me. With MagicalRecord you just call `[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];` and you get the default context just like that. MR also has amazing class methods for free like

`NSArray *array = [SomeObject findAll]`

which returns an array with all your CD objects. You can even set predicates, etc. and it's quite fast.

Comment: Sorry, CD is just short for Core Data.